# How to prevent replacing of the value for a key in Preferences?

Tags: esp32

```
#include <Preferences.h>

Preferences preferences;

const char* roomname_long = "String 1";
const char* roomname_short = "String2";
const char* roomname_long_test = "String 3";
String roomname;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  preferences.begin("app",false);

  preferences.begin("credentials", false);
  preferences.putString("roomname_long", roomname_long); 
  preferences.putString("roomname_short", roomname_short);
  preferences.putString("roomname_long", roomname_long_test);
  
  roomname = preferences.getString("roomname_long", "");

  Serial.println(roomname_long);
  Serial.println(roomname_short);
  Serial.println(roomname);

  preferences.end();
}

void loop() {

}
```

I try to save some data on my esp32 it works actually but if I try to save another variable with the same key it writes over the String before how can I interrupt that?

on the Serial Monitor I got this:

```
rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0030,len:1324
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40078000,len:13508
load:0x40080400,len:3604
entry 0x400805f0
String 1
String 2
String 3
```

I want that if I put another variable in "roomname_long" key it must not be overwritten.

So it should be stay on String 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `isKey` to test if the preferences key is already set.

```
preferences.putString("roomname_long", roomname_long);
preferences.putString("roomname_short", roomname_short);
if (!preferences.isKey("roomname_long")) {
  preferences.putString("roomname_long", roomname_long_test);
}
```